# How to insert <input> tag inside <div> tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript.
I just want to create a list with textbox and label in a row.

So that I created a **ul tag** with id cstList.

and called a function `listData()` on the **onclick event**

Inside that I am trying to create a **input tag** inside a **div tag**.

But i am getting error when trying to run this.

**Here is my code:**

```
function listData()
    {       
        //var a = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
        if(sessionStorage == null)
        {
            alert("Session storage not supported here");
        }
        else
        {
            var ss = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
            alert("storage value is: "+ss);
        }
    var rows = prompt('Please type in the number of required rows');
    var listCode = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        var listID = 'list_' + i.toString();
        var divID = 'div_' + i.toString();      
            listCode += '<li id="' + listID + '" onclick="itemClicked(this.id);"><div id = "'+ divID + '"> <input type= 'text' id= 'boltQTY' name= 'boltQTY' value = 'abc' size="5"/> </div></li>';
    }
    document.getElementById('cstList').innerHTML = listCode;
    }
```

This is the above line where i am getting error: *Unexpected Identifier*

```
 listCode += '<li id="' + listID + '" onclick="itemClicked(this.id);"><div id = "'+ divID + '"> <input type= 'text' id= 'boltQTY' name= 'boltQTY' value = 'abc' size="5"/> </div></li>';
```

Comment: looks like you forgot a bunch of plus signs when concatenating the string

Comment: ok so i should go with the double quote.right?

Comment: yes.  that is correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using single quotes and that is breaking the string.

```
<input type= 'text' id= 'boltQTY' name= 'boltQTY' value = 'abc' size="5"/>
```

should be:

```
<input type= "text" id= "boltQTY" name= "boltQTY" value = "abc" size="5"/>
```

Comment: thts really nice. I got the solution quickly. Thanks a lot

Comment: i met with one more issue here. the input boxes are placed perfectly. but why the string is not getting entered here. I removed onclick from this. then to its not getting input

Answer (score 1):

That has to be double-single-single-double

```
listCode += "<li id='" + listID + "' onclick='itemClicked(this.id);'><div id = '"+ divID + "'> <input type='text' id='boltQTY' name='boltQTY' value='abc' size='5'/> </div></li>";

variable = "string" + var1 + "string=' " + var2 +"' ";
```

Simply make sure plus sign (+) is in between double quotes ("")

Comment: i met with one more issue here. the input boxes are placed perfectly. but why the string is not getting entered here. I removed onclick from this. then to its not getting input